# JavaFX FXML Loader

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I am trying to load an FXML file as I am learning JavaFX. I made a FXML File and tried to load it but I kept on getting an error. I have checked through many tutorials and examples and I don't know what I am doing wrong! The error I was getting was:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Jacob/Desktop/JavaFX/JavaFX/builds/main/login.fxml%20:9

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at main.Test.start(Test.java:21)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      FXML.controllers.loginScenceController
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
Exception running application main.Test
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:      FXML.controllers.loginScenceController

Comment: Post the opening tag of the root element in the fxml. What is the name and the package of your controller class? `FXML.controllers.loginScenceController` doesn't seem to be the correct fully qualified name.

Comment: I fixed those things, but the "FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)" is still calling and error

Answer (score 1):

There must be some errors in your controller class or your .fxml file, put some souts and check where is the error coming from

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer, right? So please post it as a comment (once you'll have enough rep to do so :) Just noticed that the question is not answerable, missing too many details .. so removed the downvote again .. nevertheless, the comment still stands :)

Comment: ah thank you kleopatra, I will do so